# What kind of filter is z / (z + 0.5)?

Tags: z-transform, digital-filters

z / (z - e^-aT) is a low pass filter.

z / (z - 1) is an integrator.

What is z / (z + 0.5) ?

In the time domain, it is Yn = Xn - 0.5Yn-1.  It changes sign every iteration. Is this useful or should it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

$$H(z)= \frac{z}{z+0.5}$$

We have a pole at $z=-0.5$ resulting in a high pass response with finite attenuation at DC. Something that changes sign each iteration is often associated with a high-pass frequency response. This particular case is indeed useful if that is what was desired: It can be used to equalize frequency roll-off such as the Sin(x)/x frequency response associated with D/A converters and CIC filters (for example). See the achieved response below, we could easily scale the result to normalize the DC gain to one and we get a compensatory gain versus frequency with fairly linear phase out to 3/10 of the sampling rate.

[image: response]